# Modifying entries in python astropy table

Tags: python, astropy

New to Python, I don't understand the outcome of the following operations.
I read a table from a file using astropy.Table

```
data = Table.read(image_data_file, format='ascii')
```

Then I make a new identical table:

```
data2 = data
```

When a change an entry (or a whole column) in new table "data2", this is changed also in the original one "data".

```
data2['col2'] = 0
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `data2 = data.copy()` to make a copy instead of a reference to the same data.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered many times here but I don't remember under what name.

in python, if you do:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b.append(4)
b[2] = 5
```

at then end, a and b will both have the exact same data.

This is because b = a, so actually, python points both the variables to the same memory address behind the scene.

Comment: thanks: i was not able to find a similar question. 
But what surprised me is that the situaiton is different for calar values. 
I mean:
    x = 1
    y = x 
    y = y+1

at the end , x and y are different, so in this case the two variables are not poiting to the same address?

Comment: because y = x makes it point to the same address, but then y = y + 1 destroys the reference to x and this time takes the value of y and adds 1 to it (it works because y is of type int or float)